# sql error in visual studio

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio

why I am getting the following error?

> Error 11  SQL71006: Only one statement is allowed per batch. A batch
>   separator, such as 'GO', might be required between
>   statements.   dbo.Table_1 1   1

Here is my code:

```
  IF OBJECT_ID('Database1') IS NOT NULL
            DROP TABLE Table_1;

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table]
(
    [departament] VARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
    [specializare] VARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL, 
    [student] VARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL, 
    [profesor] VARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL
)
```

Comment: I hope you don't actually name your table `Table`.

Comment: Well, it would be worse if it was named `[View]` ;). But it's just a simplification.  The name used in the OBJECT_ID should be probably something like `'Database1.dbo.Table_1'` though. Funny that you don't need a GO in SSMS, probably because of the auto-commit.

Comment: The reason why this happens is described here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/34661/91898

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a `GO` between the Statements.

```
    IF OBJECT_ID('Database1') IS NOT NULL
            DROP TABLE Table_1;
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table]
(
    [departament] VARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
    [specializare] VARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL, 
    [student] VARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL, 
    [profesor] VARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL
)
```